# Dynamically create a public method in a private method

Tags: ruby

I have code in a class that dynamically creates methods using `define_method`. I want to split it into two parts to make the code more understandable. I need to put a part of the code into a private block.

Here is how my code looks:

```
class Foo
  ["bar", "baz"].each do |method|
     create_method(method)
  end

  private
  def create_method(name)
    define_method(name) do
      puts "HELL"
    end
  end
end

Foo.new.bar
```

> `create_method' for Foo:Class (NoMethodError)

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: please, provide the instances for more clarity

Comment: I guess that my code doesn't work because when I call `create_method` I'm into the class context and not the instance context. Given that this `create_method` is an instance method, it can't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. The error you are getting has absolutely nothing to do with `private` or `public` at all. The error message says that the method `create_method` cannot be found. There are two reasons for that:

1. You are calling it before it is defined. You need to move the call to `create_method` *after* its definition.
2. `create_method` is defined as an instance method, i.e. for calling it on *instances* of `Foo`, but you are calling it on `Foo` itself. You have to define it as a method somewhere in `Foo`'s class (i.e. [`Class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html)), one of its ancestors (e.g. [`Module`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html)), or `Foo`'s singleton class.

I will define it as a singleton method of `Foo` here, but if the method really is as generic as you have showed in your example, then it probably rather belongs in `Module` instead.

```
class Foo
  class << self
    private
    def create_method(name)
      define_method(name) do
        puts "HELL"
      end
    end
  end

  ["bar", "baz"].each do |method|
     create_method(method)
  end
end

Foo.new.bar
# HELL
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what went wrong for you, but this seemed to work for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class C

  def initialize
    create_method
  end


  def create_method
    private_create_method
  end


  private
  def private_create_method
    class << self
      define_method(:foo) { puts "I am a public method." }
    end
  end
end

C.new.foo # outputs: I am a public method.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
MyClass.instance_eval { public :public_method }
```

Or run:

```
public :public_method
```

from within the MyClass class.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `private_create_method` with

```
def private_create_method
  self.class.send(:define_method, :foo) { puts "I am a public method." }
end
```

then

```
C.new.foo
I am a public method
```